# how do I create a "load" window with text inside in a web app?

Tags: html

My inquiry is rather simple for a beginner's web developer, but unfortunately my web programming knowledge is archaic.

I have a URL that runs some server-side code and spits out some html code. I want to have an HTML page, where I click on "refresh" and the server-side code URL is loaded, and then printed inside a window in the HTML page (or updates some  etc.) *without* having to reload the tab/page in the browser. While it is loading the URL, I would like an animation of a "loading" icon to appear (just like in a flash app) in the middle of the frame where the text is supposed to appear.

Very trivial, but I am not sure how to do it.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is *not* trivial, and included implementing a lot of different things on both the server and client side.

Comment: is it really not trivial? I already have the code that implements the server-side code. I just need the HTML client-side code that refreshes this URL from inside a window, instead of reloading the whole page. It is everywhere these days in the web.

Comment: Facebook and Twitter *both* got aspects of this wrong (i.e.: they had bad bugs) when they first implemented this sort of technology, so yes, it's non-trivial to get correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure which technology you are using but I am doing the same in JavaScript and AJAX. For demo, you can visit, http://www.charkula.com/singapore_vieweventdetails.asp?id=16, click on "**Check Availability or Buy Tickets**" button.

What it does is when the button is clicked, it calls and executes the code on the server and fetches the data from database, and same goes for other combo's after this.

Let me know if you want the code for both JavaScript & AJAX.